# Make $_GET variable available within function scope

Tags: php

How to pass a `$_GET` variable into function?

```
$_GET['TEST']='some word';
public function example() {       
   //pass $_GET['TEST'] into here
}
```

When I try to access `$_GET['TEST']` in my function, it is empty.

Comment: This is flawed. This is not a function but a method...where is your class?

Comment: I think you should understand the very basics of php variables, php functions and general OOP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `$_GET` array is one of PHPs [superglobals](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php) so you can use it as-is within the function:

```
public function example() {       
   print $_GET['TEST'];
}
```

In general, you pass a variable (argument) like so:

```
public function example($arg1) {       
   print $arg1;
}
example($myNonGlobalVar);
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is a function and not an object method then you pass the parameter like so

```
function example($test) {
    echo $test;
}
```

and then you call that function like so

```
$_GET['test'] = 'test';
example($_GET['test']);
```

output being

```
test
```

However if this is an object you could do this

```
class Test {

    public function example($test) {
        echo $test;
    }
}
```

and you would then call it like so

```
$_GET['test'] = 'test';
$testObj = new Test;
$testObj->example($_GET['test']);
```

and the output should be

```
test
```

I hope this helps you out.

Answer (score 0):

First of all - you should not set anything to superglobals (`$_GET`, `$_POST`, etc).

So we convert it to:

```
$test = 'some word';
```

And if you want to pass it to the function just do something like:

```
function example($value) {       
   echo $value;
}
```

And call this function with:

```
example($test);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function example ($value) {
  $value; // available here
}
example($_GET['TEST']);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function example($parameter)
{
     do something with $parameter;
}

$variable = 'some word';

example($variable);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply declare the value for the variable by

declare the function by

```
function employee($name,$email) {
 // function statements
}

$name = $_GET["name"];
$email = $_GET["email"];
```

calling the function by

```
employee($name,$email);
```